# Join one array with multiple index php

Tags: php, arrays

How to join 2 arrays with multiple index into 1 array ?
I have array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [wd[wd5][amount]] => 1.00
            [wd[wd5][address]] => 1BitcoinAddress
            [wd[wd5][currency]] => BTC

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [wd[wd7][amount]] => 1.00
            [wd[wd7][address]] => 1BitcoinAddress
            [wd[wd7][currency]] => BTC

        )

)
```

I want to convert/change/merge that array into something exactly like this

```
array(
        'wd[wd5][amount]' => 1.00,
        'wd[wd5][address]' => '1BitcoinAddress',
        'wd[wd5][currency]' => 'BTC',
        'wd[wd7][amount]' => 0.0001,
        'wd[wd7][address]' => '1BitcoinAddress',
        'wd[wd7][currency]' => 'BTC'

);
```

how do I do that ?

Comment: what is the actual structure of `[wd[wd5][amount]]` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Just like I posted. Just one array. I need to post it to Some API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop the array using foreach and create an new array.

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $value){
    foreach($value as $k=>$v){
        $new_array[$k] = $v;
    }
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [wd[wd5][amount]] => 1.00
    [wd[wd5][address]] => 1BitcoinAddress
    [wd[wd5][currency]] => BTC
    [wd[wd7][amount]] => 1.00
    [wd[wd7][address]] => 1BitcoinAddress
    [wd[wd7][currency]] => BTC
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) and [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
<?php

$array = [

    [
        "[wd[wd5][amount]]" => 1.00,
        "[wd[wd5][address]]" => "1BitcoinAddress",
        "[wd[wd5][currency]]" => "BTC"
    ],
    [
        "[wd[wd7][amount]]" => 1.00,
        "[wd[wd7][address]]" => "1BitcoinAddress",
        "[wd[wd7][currency]]" => "BTC"
    ]
];


$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Nice and simplez, +1

Comment: I appreciate the quick and kind comeback!

Answer (score 1):

you can do this like:

```
$result = array();
foreach($array as $item) {
    $result = array_merge($result, $item);
}
```

here `$result` is a new blank array, and `$array` is the array to merge.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) and [RecursiveArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php).

Though I'm liking @BilalAkbar's answer abit more now for the simplicity.

```
<?php
$array = [
    [
        'wd[wd5][amount]' => 1.00,
        'wd[wd5][address]' => '1BitcoinAddress',
        'wd[wd5][currency]' => 'BTC',
    ],
        [
        'wd[wd7][amount]' => 1.00,
        'wd[wd7][address]' => '1BitcoinAddress',
        'wd[wd7][currency]' => 'BTC'
    ],

];

$result = [];
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
         new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)
) as $key => $value) {
  $result[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($result);
/*
Array
(
    [wd[wd5][amount]] => 1
    [wd[wd5][address]] => 1BitcoinAddress
    [wd[wd5][currency]] => BTC
    [wd[wd7][amount]] => 1
    [wd[wd7][address]] => 1BitcoinAddress
    [wd[wd7][currency]] => BTC
)
*/
```

https://3v4l.org/0fCKj

Answer (score 0):

Use array_merge to merge combine the arrays.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
<?php

$arrayWithSubarrays = array(
    array(
        "[wd[wd5][amount]]" => 1.00,
        "[wd[wd5][address]]" => "1BitcoinAddress",
        "[wd[wd5][currency]]" => "BTC"
    ),
    array(
        "[wd[wd7][amount]]" => 1.00,
        "[wd[wd7][address]]" => "1BitcoinAddress",
        "[wd[wd7][currency]]" => "BTC"
    )
);

// merge each array explicitly:
$mergedArray1 = array_merge($arrayWithSubarrays[0],$arrayWithSubarrays[1]);

// or merge as many as you have in the array:
$mergedArray2 = array();
foreach($arrayWithSubarrays as $array) {
    $mergedArray2 = array_merge($mergedArray2, $array);
}

// (mergedArray1 contains the same data as mergedArray2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here answer, but you have 2 solution one different key then below answer.
otherwise only save array last values beacause every time  3 keys same.

hope you understand.

```php
<?php

$a = array
(
     array
        (
            'wd[wd[amount]]' => '1.00',
            '[wd[wd5][address]]' => '1BitcoinAddress',
            '[wd[wd5][currency]]' => 'BTC'


        ),

    array
        (
            'wd[wd[amount1]]' => '1.00',
            '[wd[wd5][address1]]' => '1BitcoinAddress',
            '[wd[wd5][currency1]]' => 'BTC'
        )

);
$total = count($a);
$p = array();
$q = array();
$pq = array();
for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++){
    $tarray = $a[$i];
    foreach($tarray as $k=>$v){
        array_push($p,$k);
        array_push($q,$v);

    }       
}
$pq = array_combine($p,$q);
print_r($pq);

?>
```